# A message body reader for Java class X, and Java type class Y, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, json, jaxb

Here is my code. I'm calling a RESTful service that returns JSON of an entity type MexpCategoriesDTOWrapper.

```
String url = "http://" + servlet.getServletContext().getAttribute(ServicesManagerServlet.MPDS_HOST_NAME) +
        ":" + servlet.getServletContext().getAttribute(ServicesManagerServlet.MPDS_PORT_NAME) + "/mexpCategoryRates";

ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
MexpCategoriesDTOWrapper mcdtow = response.getEntity(MexpCategoriesDTOWrapper.class);
```

here is the stack trace

```
11:05:41,272 INFO  [SamExceptionHandler] Exception while processing request
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class com.pronto.mpds.wrapper.MexpCategoriesDTOWrapper, and Java type class com.pronto.mpds.wrapper.MexpCategoriesDTOWrapper, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517)
    at com.rc.mexp.action.enrollment.RateCardAction.execute(RateCardAction.java:48)
    at com.rc.mexp.action.SamAction.execute(SamAction.java:57)
    at com.rc.commonbusinesswebapp.action.BusinessWebappLoggedAction.executeWithLogging(BusinessWebappLoggedAction.java:66)
    at com.rc.commonbusinesswebapp.action.BusinessWebappLoggedAction.execute(BusinessWebappLoggedAction.java:46)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at com.rc.commonbusinesswebapp.controller.BusinessWebappRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(BusinessWebappRequestProcessor.java:202)
    at com.rc.commonbusinesswebapp.controller.BusinessWebappRequestProcessor.process(BusinessWebappRequestProcessor.java:522)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.rc.commonbusinesswebapp.servlet.filter.GlobalRootManager.doFilter(GlobalRootManager.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.rc.model.persistence.proxyhandler.TransactionHandler.invoke(TransactionHandler.java:44)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.rc.model.persistence.proxyhandler.SessionHandler.invoke(SessionHandler.java:42)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.rc.model.persistence.proxyhandler.SessionHandler.invoke(SessionHandler.java:42)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.rc.commonwebapp.servlet.filter.SessionTXManager.doFilter(SessionTXManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

i traced it to here in ClientResponse:

```
private <T> T getEntity(Class<T> c, Type type) {
    if (getStatus() == 204) {
        throw new UniformInterfaceException(this);
    }

    MediaType mediaType = getType();
    if (mediaType == null) {
        mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE;
    }

    final MessageBodyReader<T> br = workers.getMessageBodyReader(
            c, type,
            EMPTY_ANNOTATIONS, mediaType);
    if (br == null) {
        close();
        String message = "A message body reader for Java class " + c.getName() +
                ", and Java type " + type +
                ", and MIME media type " + mediaType + " was not found";
        LOGGER.severe(message);
        Map<MediaType, List<MessageBodyReader>> m = workers.getReaders(mediaType);
        LOGGER.severe("The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:\n" +
                workers.readersToString(m));

        throw new ClientHandlerException(message);
    }
    ...
}
```

which calls MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader() method:

```
public <T> MessageBodyReader<T> getMessageBodyReader(Class<T> c, Type t, 
        Annotation[] as, 
        MediaType mediaType) {

    MessageBodyReader reader;

    if(!customReaderProviders.isEmpty()) {
        reader = _getMessageBodyReader(c, t, as, mediaType, customReaderProviders);
        if(reader != null)
            return reader;
    }
    reader = _getMessageBodyReader(c, t, as, mediaType, readerProviders);

    return reader;
}
```

`customReaderProviders` is empty. When I look at MessageBOdyFactory initReaders() method, I don't see anything getting registered in customReaderProviders for my class.

```
private void initReaders() {
    this.customReaderProviders = new KeyComparatorHashMap<MediaType, List<MessageBodyReader>>(
            MEDIA_TYPE_COMPARATOR);
    this.readerProviders = new KeyComparatorHashMap<MediaType, List<MessageBodyReader>>(
            MEDIA_TYPE_COMPARATOR);

    if(deprecatedProviderPrecedence) {
        initReaders(this.readerProviders, providerServices.getProvidersAndServices(MessageBodyReader.class));
    } else {
        initReaders(this.customReaderProviders, providerServices.getProviders(MessageBodyReader.class));
        initReaders(this.readerProviders, providerServices.getServices(MessageBodyReader.class));
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to have passed something in somewhere that I'm not passing in?

I have confirmed that I have the same jaxb jars (jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1) in my client as used in the service. No joy.

I have confirmed that the correct output is being returned from the service, both when I call a CURL from the command line and in the debug output when running the client.